# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS - Unable to boot into Windows from Grub menu

Tags: xubuntu, 18.04, uefi, grub-efi

I have successfully installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. When I start the system I'm shown the Grub Menu. When I select Windows it throws a ***"Boot Configuration data for your PC is missing or contains errors"***

When I checked the Bios Settings, I noticed the the boot was set to **Legacy Software** and not **UEFI**. Changing this to UEFI and rebooting I don't see the Grub Menu anymore and it loads Windows directly.

**Work Around:**
I have to manually change this each time I want to load Windows.

**Tried:**

- I have already updated the Grub, this didn't help.
- I ran the sudo -H gedit /boot/grub/custom.cfg, and pasted and saved the below contents,

`This entry should work for any version of Windows installed for UEFI booting

**menuentry "Windows (UEFI)" {
 search --set=root --file /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
 chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}**`

I got the below error:
**** (gedit:2203): WARNING **: 19:45:17.602: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-position not supported**

Also tried this - [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix/921722#921722)

The windows option is grayed out, and trying out recommended boot repair, an error shows that the boot mode should be set to UEFI and then this can be tried, this is exactly my problem if I set it to UEFI then Ubuntu doesn't load.

The BootInfo Result Script:

```
                  Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 
    796555264 of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this 
    location and looks in partition 85 for .

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /bootmgr /boot/bcd

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /tmp/BootInfo-j71gTQU0/sda4: unknown filesystem type ''.

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda8: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda9: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       BIOS Boot partition
    Boot sector type:  Grub2's core.img
    Boot sector info: 

sda10: _________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sda: 465,8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                   1   976,773,167   976,773,167  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1           2,048     2,050,047     2,048,000 Windows Recovery Environment (Windows)
/dev/sda2       2,050,048     2,582,527       532,480 EFI System partition
/dev/sda3       2,582,528     4,630,527     2,048,000 -
/dev/sda4       4,630,528     4,892,671       262,144 Microsoft Reserved Partition (Windows)
/dev/sda5       4,892,672   796,554,467   791,661,796 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda6     880,441,344   882,401,279     1,959,936 Windows Recovery Environment (Windows)
/dev/sda7     882,401,280   934,830,079    52,428,800 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda8     934,830,080   976,773,119    41,943,040 Windows Recovery Environment (Windows)
/dev/sda9     796,555,264   796,557,311         2,048 BIOS Boot partition
/dev/sda10    796,557,312   880,441,343    83,884,032 Data partition (Linux)

"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop1                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop10                                             squashfs   
/dev/loop11                                             squashfs   
/dev/loop12                                             squashfs   
/dev/loop2                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop3                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop4                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop5                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop6                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop7                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop8                                              squashfs   
/dev/loop9                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        3606A88106A84429                       ntfs       WINRE_DRV
/dev/sda10       6381c640-07b1-4c5e-8407-e5d8d4c0ca9f   ext4       
/dev/sda2        BEAA-D4B4                              vfat       SYSTEM_DRV
/dev/sda3        F8AB-6693                              vfat       LRS_ESP
/dev/sda4                                                          
/dev/sda5        D0FAAF33FAAF152E                       ntfs       Windows8_OS
/dev/sda6        6AE0DA26E0D9F7F1                       ntfs       
/dev/sda7        BC52B1BD52B17D28                       ntfs       LENOVO
/dev/sda8        F61AB3BB1AB376E9                       ntfs       PBR_DRV
/dev/sda9                                                          

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sda10       /                        ext4       (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)


========================== sda10/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt10'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt10 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt10 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt10  6381c640-07b1-4c5e-8407-e5d8d4c0ca9f
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6381c640-07b1-4c5e-8407-e5d8d4c0ca9f
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 10 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30,0; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=1
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-6381c640-07b1-4c5e-8407-e5d8d4c0ca9f' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt10'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt10 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt10 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt10  6381c640-07b1-4c5e-8407-e5d8d4c0ca9f
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6381c640-07b1-4c5e-8407-e5d8d4c0ca9f
    fi
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-29-generic root=UUID=6381c640-07b1-4c5e-8407-e5d8d4c0ca9f ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-6381c640-07b1-4c5e-8407-e5d8d4c0ca9f' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-29-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-29-generic-advanced-6381c640-07b1-4c5e-8407-e5d8d4c0ca9f' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt10'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt10 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt10 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt10  6381c640-07b1-4c5e-8407-e5d8d4c0ca9f
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6381c640-07b1-4c5e-8407-e5d8d4c0ca9f
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.15.0-29-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-29-generic root=UUID=6381c640-07b1-4c5e-8407-e5d8d4c0ca9f ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-29-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-29-generic-recovery-6381c640-07b1-4c5e-8407-e5d8d4c0ca9f' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt10'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt10 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt10 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt10  6381c640-07b1-4c5e-8407-e5d8d4c0ca9f
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6381c640-07b1-4c5e-8407-e5d8d4c0ca9f
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.15.0-29-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-29-generic root=UUID=6381c640-07b1-4c5e-8407-e5d8d4c0ca9f ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-20-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-20-generic-advanced-6381c640-07b1-4c5e-8407-e5d8d4c0ca9f' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt10'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt10 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt10 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt10  6381c640-07b1-4c5e-8407-e5d8d4c0ca9f
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6381c640-07b1-4c5e-8407-e5d8d4c0ca9f
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.15.0-20-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic root=UUID=6381c640-07b1-4c5e-8407-e5d8d4c0ca9f ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-20-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-20-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-20-generic-recovery-6381c640-07b1-4c5e-8407-e5d8d4c0ca9f' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt10'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt10 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt10 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt10  6381c640-07b1-4c5e-8407-e5d8d4c0ca9f
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6381c640-07b1-4c5e-8407-e5d8d4c0ca9f
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.15.0-20-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic root=UUID=6381c640-07b1-4c5e-8407-e5d8d4c0ca9f ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-20-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+)' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt10'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt10 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt10 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt10  6381c640-07b1-4c5e-8407-e5d8d4c0ca9f
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6381c640-07b1-4c5e-8407-e5d8d4c0ca9f
    fi
    knetbsd /boot/memtest86+.elf
}
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt10'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt10 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt10 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt10  6381c640-07b1-4c5e-8407-e5d8d4c0ca9f
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6381c640-07b1-4c5e-8407-e5d8d4c0ca9f
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows Recovery Environment (on /dev/sda3)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-F8AB-6693' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    set root='hd0,gpt3'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt3 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt3  F8AB-6693
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root F8AB-6693
    fi
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
menuentry 'Windows 8 (on /dev/sda5)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-D0FAAF33FAAF152E' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,gpt5'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt5  D0FAAF33FAAF152E
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root D0FAAF33FAAF152E
    fi
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda10/etc/fstab: ===============================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda10 during installation
UUID=6381c640-07b1-4c5e-8407-e5d8d4c0ca9f /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda10: Location of files loaded by Grub: ===================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================

Unknown GPT Partiton Type
e7afbfbf4fa38a449a5b6213eb736c22
Unknown BootLoader on sda2

00000000  eb 58 90 4d 53 44 4f 53  35 2e 30 00 02 08 fe 1b  |.X.MSDOS5.0.....|
00000010  02 00 00 00 00 f8 00 00  3f 00 ff 00 00 48 1f 00  |........?....H..|
00000020  00 20 08 00 01 02 00 00  00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  |. ..............|
00000030  01 00 06 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  80 00 29 b4 d4 aa be 4e  4f 20 4e 41 4d 45 20 20  |..)....NO NAME  |
00000050  20 20 46 41 54 33 32 20  20 20 33 c9 8e d1 bc f4  |  FAT32   3.....|
00000060  7b 8e c1 8e d9 bd 00 7c  88 56 40 88 4e 02 8a 56  |{......|.V@.N..V|
00000070  40 b4 41 bb aa 55 cd 13  72 10 81 fb 55 aa 75 0a  |@.A..U..r...U.u.|
00000080  f6 c1 01 74 05 fe 46 02  eb 2d 8a 56 40 b4 08 cd  |...t..F..-.V@...|
00000090  13 73 05 b9 ff ff 8a f1  66 0f b6 c6 40 66 0f b6  |.s......f...@f..|
000000a0  d1 80 e2 3f f7 e2 86 cd  c0 ed 06 41 66 0f b7 c9  |...?.......Af...|
000000b0  66 f7 e1 66 89 46 f8 83  7e 16 00 75 39 83 7e 2a  |f..f.F..~..u9.~*|
000000c0  00 77 33 66 8b 46 1c 66  83 c0 0c bb 00 80 b9 01  |.w3f.F.f........|
000000d0  00 e8 2c 00 e9 a8 03 a1  f8 7d 80 c4 7c 8b f0 ac  |..,......}..|...|
000000e0  84 c0 74 17 3c ff 74 09  b4 0e bb 07 00 cd 10 eb  |..t.<.t.........|
000000f0  ee a1 fa 7d eb e4 a1 7d  80 eb df 98 cd 16 cd 19  |...}...}........|
00000100  66 60 80 7e 02 00 0f 84  20 00 66 6a 00 66 50 06  |f`.~.... .fj.fP.|
00000110  53 66 68 10 00 01 00 b4  42 8a 56 40 8b f4 cd 13  |Sfh.....B.V@....|
00000120  66 58 66 58 66 58 66 58  eb 33 66 3b 46 f8 72 03  |fXfXfXfX.3f;F.r.|
00000130  f9 eb 2a 66 33 d2 66 0f  b7 4e 18 66 f7 f1 fe c2  |..*f3.f..N.f....|
00000140  8a ca 66 8b d0 66 c1 ea  10 f7 76 1a 86 d6 8a 56  |..f..f....v....V|
00000150  40 8a e8 c0 e4 06 0a cc  b8 01 02 cd 13 66 61 0f  |@............fa.|
00000160  82 74 ff 81 c3 00 02 66  40 49 75 94 c3 42 4f 4f  |.t.....f@Iu..BOO|
00000170  54 4d 47 52 20 20 20 20  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |TMGR    ........|
00000180  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 0d 0a 44 69  |..............Di|
000001b0  73 6b 20 65 72 72 6f 72  ff 0d 0a 50 72 65 73 73  |sk error...Press|
000001c0  20 61 6e 79 20 6b 65 79  20 74 6f 20 72 65 73 74  | any key to rest|
000001d0  61 72 74 0d 0a 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |art.............|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ac 01 b9 01 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200


=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

cat: /tmp/BootInfo-j71gTQU0/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
```

Comment: UEFI & BIOS are not compatible. They write hardware data differently to hard drive for operating system. You then can only boot from UEFI boot menu. Or you can only boot from grub other systems installed in same boot mode. But if Windows is UEFI and Ubuntu BIOS/CSM/Legacy, you can easily convert install by uninstalling grub-pc and installing grub-efi-amd64. Usually easier with Boot-Repair's advanced options when ubuntu live installer is booted in UEFI mode and Boot-Repair added with ppa. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair